# Jquery libraries having compatibility issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I downloaded a Jquery plugin for image transitions from [here](http://workshop.rs/2009/12/image-gallery-with-fancy-transitions-effects/).

And now my original jquery is not working :(

I wrote this in the file where I am having all my original code (i.e myjs.js):

```
$('#slidercont').jqFancyTransitions({ width: 985, height: 493 ,delay: 2000,stripDelay: 50,titleSpeed: 1000});
```

Everything works fine when I comment this line.

Here is the part where I have included the jquery libraries:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>    //The Jquery library
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myjs.js"></script>         //where I have written all my js code
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>
<script src="js/jqFancyTransitions.1.8.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     //this is the new library I included.
```

What can I do to make them work together?
Should I write code for separate libraries in separate files.

I tried changing the order of including files but that didn't help.

Any suggestions here?

**UPDATE**:

I have the main page where slide show is there and I have included all the scripts there. And in another the page where I am using self-written JS (where problem occurs) I have included all the JS files except the plugin for transition. Do I need to change it there?

CODE snippet from `myjs.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// ... some other jquery code

    $('#slidercont').jqFancyTransitions({ width: 985, height: 493 ,delay: 2000,stripDelay: 50,titleSpeed: 1000});

// ... some other jquery code       

});
```

Comment: What error do you get in the console? What happens when you walk through the code with the debugger built into your browser?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, The error in the console is: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function `

Comment: Good, that was what I guessed. Fixing the script order should fix it.

Comment: I reordered the script order. Still no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the jquery plugin in my other pages also, since I was having myjs.js file included (which has all my jquery code including that part using code from jquery plugin).

The error was due to the fact that the pages having myjs.js file included and plugin not included was having problem:

```
 $('#slidercont').jqFancyTransitions({ width: 985, height: 493 ,delay: 2000,stripDelay: 50,titleSpeed: 1000});
```

since it couldn't find the corresponding function.

I added the plugin there also and it's now working.. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer**:

From your comments, it suggests that the plug-in's script file isn't loading (look for errors in the network console). That suggests that the path to it isn't correct. If you correct the path, the problem should go away (but I'd still suggest changing the load order per the below).

> I have the main page where slide show is there and I have included all the scripts there. And in another the page where I am using self-written JS (where problem occurs) I have included all the JS files except the plugin for transition. Do I need to change it there?

There's no need to include the plug-in on pages that don't use it.

---

**Original Answer**:

You have your scripts in the wrong order, so when you try to call `jqFancyTransitions`, it doesn't exist on the `jQuery` object yet (in the console, you should be seeing `Error: undefined is not a function` or similar).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>    //The Jquery library
<script src="js/jqFancyTransitions.1.8.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     //this is the new library I included.
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myjs.js"></script>         //where I have written all my js code
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>
```

(I don't know what's in `slider.js`, but you may want to move that up, too.)

The general load order is:

1. jQuery
2. Any jQuery plugins you intend to use
3. Your code

Comment: (If your code calling `jqFancyTransitions` is in a `ready` callback, though, this won't be the problem. You probably still want to fix the order, though.)

Comment: You can't be too sure about the plugin, but always wrap your code with in the ready callback. Like T.J said, Ordering is very important too.

Comment: @Popsyjunior: *"...always wrap your code with in the ready callback."* No, that's not necessary. If you control where the script tags go, just put them at the end of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag. No need for `ready` except in code where you don't know where the script tag will be.

Comment: @J.T. Crowder: _"..except in code where you don't know where the script tag will be"_ Of course we don't know where the script tags are placed. I think it's better to play safe. I use the shorthand `$(function(){/*My Code..*/});`

Comment: @Popsyjunior: *We* don't know, but presumably the OP does. Waiting for `ready` when you don't need to is an anti-pattern.

Comment: I changed the order but that does not seems to work, apologies for late comment.

Comment: Do you want me to post a portion of the myjs.js file?

Comment: @Nivedita: See update, that suggests the plugin is failing to load, which suggests the path to the script file is incorrect.

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with the path. I have all my js files in the js folder. I just double checked it.

Comment: 1 think I would like to ask is, Do i need to include the transition plugin in other pages too, where I am not using the plug in ?

Comment: @Nivedita: *"Do i need to include the transition plugin in other pages too, where I am not using the plug in ?"* No, no need.

Comment: @Nivedita: Did you check the network tab in the web console for errors? There really are just two possibilities here: 1. You're calling the plugin before it's loaded, but if your code calling it is in a `ready` callback, that shouldn't be the case. 2. It's not loading at all.